# Expo react native status-bar resets when dropdown triggered on android

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo

So basically my problem is described in the title. I have set the statusbar on light mode, so the text stays white because my app is in full dark mode. But when I open a dropdown menu from `react-native-element-dropdown` it is resetting to it's default color (black). I have added pictures at the end of this post.

This is my `app.js`:

```
export default function App() {
    useEffect(() => {
        if (Platform.OS === "ios") {
            enableScreens(false);
        }
        if (Platform.OS === "android"){
            NavigationBar.setBackgroundColorAsync(colors.navBar);
            NavigationBar.setBorderColorAsync("transparent");
        }
    }, [])

    return (
        <Provider store={store}>
            <StoreProvider>
                <NavigationContainer ref={navigationRef}>
                    <StatusBar style="light" />
                    <MainNavigation/>
                </NavigationContainer>
                <MessagePopup/>
            </StoreProvider>
        </Provider>
    );
}
```

And this is my `dropdown menu`:

```
<Dropdown
                        style={[styles.dropdown]}
                        placeholderStyle={styles.placeholderStyle}
                        selectedTextStyle={styles.selectedTextStyle}
                        iconStyle={isDisabled ? styles.iconStyle2 : styles.iconStyle}
                        data={schemaTypes}
                        maxHeight={300}
                        labelField="label"
                        valueField="value"
                        placeholder={!isFocus ? 'Select schema type' : '...'}
                        value={value}
                        onFocus={() => setIsFocus(true)}
                        onBlur={() => setIsFocus(false)}
                        onChange={item => {
                            SetValue(item.value);
                            setIsFocus(false);
                            dispatch(setSessExercise([]))
                        }}
                        itemContainerStyle={{

                        }}
                        disable={isDisabled}
                    />
```

But as you can see in the pictures the top navigation bar when te dropdown is not toggled it's fine, same as the bottomnavigation bar. But when it is toggled it's not. Do you guys know why that is like that?

[image]

[image]